# fastest way to count the number of differences among rows in 2d-array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I need to compute the number of differences (~score) of all rows against all the other of a full 2d-array (score needed to compute a 'difference distance' of an array usefull for statistics). Here a simple exemple, but i need to do that on huge 2d-arrays of ~100 000 rows and thousands of rows, so I'm looking for speeding up my naive code:

```
a = numpy.array([[1,2],[1,2],[1,3],[2,3],[3,3]])
score =0
scoresquare = 0
for i in xrange(len(a)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(a)):
        scoretemp = 0
        if a[i,0]!=a[j,0] and a[i,1]!=a[j,0] and a[i,1]!=a[j,1] and a[i,0]!=a[j,1] :
            # comparison gives two different items
            scoretemp = 2
        elif (a[i]==a[j]).all():
            scoretemp = 0
        else:
            scoretemp=1
        print a[i],a[j],scoretemp, (a[i]==a[j]).all(),(a[i]==a[j]).any()
        score += scoretemp
        scoresquare += (scoretemp*scoretemp)       
print score,scoresquare
```

**a[0] is identical to a[1] so score(number of differences)=0, but has one difference with a[2] and two differences with a[3].** To compute such distance (statistics), I need intermedairy square-score and score.

```
reference_row  compared_row  score
[1 2]          [1 2]         0  
[1 2]          [1 3]         1 
[1 2]          [2 3]         1 
[1 2]          [3 3]         2  
[1 2]          [1 3]         1 
[1 2]          [2 3]         1  
[1 2]          [3 3]         2  
[1 3]          [2 3]         1  
[1 3]          [3 3]         1  
[2 3]          [3 3]         1  
Sum_score=11 Sum_scoresquare=15
```

My code is quite naive and doesn't take advantage of the full strenght of arrays so: How to accelerate such computation? Thanks for your help

Comment: Since your code works but needs to be optimized, this question may be better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) than for Stack Overflow

Comment: Looks like you're trying to get all the combinations of the rows, [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) can do that for you.

Comment: Should the score be zero if the rows are for example `[1 2]` and `[2 1]`? Also, are the values always reasonably small integers?

Comment: yes only small integers from 0 to 100 max.

Answer (score 1):

`np.in1d` searches every element of **array1** in **array2** and generates **True** for a match. So we need to negate the result using `~np.in1d`. After that `np.where` gives those indices which hold a **True** value, so `len(np.where(...))` gives the total mismatches. I hope this will help you:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1,2],[1,2],[1,3],[2,3],[3,3]])
>>> res=[len(np.where(~np.in1d(a[p],a[q]))[0]) for p in range(a.shape[0]) for q in range(p+1,a.shape[0])]
>>> res=np.array(res)
>>> Sum_score=sum(res)
>>> Sum_score_square=sum(res*res)
>>> print Sum_score, Sum_score_square
11 15
>>> k=0
>>> for i in range(a.shape[0]):
...     for j in range(i+1,a.shape[0]):
...         print a[i],a[j],res[k]
...         k+=1


[1 2] [1 2] 0
[1 2] [1 3] 1
[1 2] [2 3] 1
[1 2] [3 3] 2
[1 2] [1 3] 1
[1 2] [2 3] 1
[1 2] [3 3] 2
[1 3] [2 3] 1
[1 3] [3 3] 1
[2 3] [3 3] 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your proposal. Timeit gives 1.14 sec for your proposal and 0.38 sec for mine for 10000 repeats... I will test with bigger 2d-arrays.

Comment: You don't have to do `len(np.where(...))`, `np.countnonzero(...)` should get you the same result much faster.

Comment: Still, the bottleneck is going to be `in1d`, if you look at [the source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.8.1/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py#L283) it should be obvious that there are lots of repetition going on. Not sure how to get rid of it, though...